# Bash script case statement including test conditions not behaving

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script

I have a somewhat lengthy script (main script). I will include it all here as I believe it may be relavent to the answer so please don't hate on me. Everything in this script works. The only thing I am struggling with is case *www1) and *www2) near the end which are essentially the same. The NULL test works and data that is entered into the Zentiy boxes is handled correctly for these cases. However if I enter nothing in the corresponding Zenity fields (invoice_number & note) `else    until [[ -n "${var2}" ]]; do...` is ignored. At the end of the script I have included another more simplified script of just the case in question (simplified). When I run it there is no problem and everything works as expected. The case is just copied over from the original so I am pulling my hair out as to why the one works but not the other. Is someone willing to help on this?

The main script:

```
#!/bin/bash


work_number="$(zenity --entry --text "ENTER number of work/job entries:" --entry-text "1")"
        a=1

until
        [[ $work_number -lt $a ]]
do

input="$(zenity --forms --title="table work" --text="Add a new job" --separator="," \
       --add-entry="ENTER clientid: " \
       --add-entry="ENTER job_start, -t time without time zone, e.g. '11:45:00', seconds allways zero: " \
       --add-entry="ENTER job_finish, -t time without time zone, e.g. '11:45:00', seconds allways zero: " \
       --add-entry="ENTER number_catchers, -t numeric, must be 0 if no waste has been collected or NULL if it has yet to be assigned to a tip run: " \
       --add-entry="ENTER mower_front, -t numeric:" \
       --add-entry="ENTER mower_back, -t numeric: " \
       --add-entry="ENTER categoryid: " \
       --add-entry="ENTER price, -t numeric: " \
       --add-entry="ENTER invoice_number, -t text: " \
       --add-entry="ENTER note, -t text: " \
       --add-entry="ENTER a tip_runid, -t integer: ")"

psql -tA -U chh1 -d crewdb -c "SELECT SETVAL('work_workid_seq', (SELECT MAX(workid) FROM work), true);" >/dev/null 2>&1
dlink="$(psql -tA -U chh1 -d crewdb -c "SELECT MAX(date_linkid) FROM date_link;")"

startt="$(echo "$input" | awk -F, -v  OFS=, '{print $2}')"
finisht="$(echo "$input" | awk -F, -v  OFS=, '{print $3}')"

st="$( date --date="$startt" +%s  2>/dev/null )"
ft="$( date --date="$finisht" +%s 2>/dev/null )"

if [ -n "$st" -a "$ft" ] ; then

    startt="$(date +%H:%M  -d "$startt"  )"
    finisht="$(date +%H:%M -d "$finisht" )"
    tzdiff="$(( ft - st ))"
else
    tzdiff=0
fi

while [[  ( ( ! "$startt"   =~ ^[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$ ) && ( ! "$startt"  =~ ^[0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]$ ) ) ||
          ( ( ! "$finisht"  =~ ^[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$ ) && ( ! "$finisht" =~ ^[0-2][0-3]:[0-5][0-9]$ ) ) ||
          ( "$tzdiff" -le 0 )  ]];
do
    var2="$(zenity --forms --title="job start time and/or job finish time are incorrect" --text "Add a job start time and finish_time"  --separator="," \
                   --add-entry="WARNING! Something went wrong. Please enter a valid job start time, e.g. 8:20: " \
                   --add-entry="WARNING! Something went wrong. Please enter a valid job finish time, e.g. 12:30: ")"
    tzdiff=0

    if [ -n "$var2" ] ; then
       b1=$(echo "$var2" | cut -d, -f1 )
       b2=$(echo "$var2" | cut -d, -f2 )

       if [ -n "$b1" -a -n "$b2"  ] ; then
           tz1=$( date --date="$b1" +%s 2>/dev/null )
           tz2=$( date --date="$b2" +%s 2>/dev/null )

           if [ -n "$tz1" -a -n "$tz2" ] ; then
              startt=$(date +%H:%M -d "$b1" )
              finisht=$(date +%H:%M -d "$b2" )
              tzdiff=$(( tz2 - tz1 ))
           fi
       fi
    fi
done

var2="$startt,$finisht"

input="$( echo "$input" | awk -v vard="$dlink" -v vart="$var2" 'BEGIN {  FS="," } { print $1"xxx1" "," vard"ddd" "," vart "," $4"xxx2" "," $5"xxx3" "," $6"xxx4" "," $7"xxx5" "," $8"xxx6" "," $9"www1" "," $10"www2" "," $11"xxx7" ; }' )"

IFS=, read -ra array1 <<<"$input"
out=""

for i in "${array1[@]}"; do

        case "$i" in
        *ddd) out="$out,${i/%ddd/}";;
            
        *xxx1)  if [[ "${i/%xxx1/}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
                
                out="$out,${i/%xxx1/}"

                elif [[ "${i/%xxx1/}" = NULL ]]; then

                    out="$out,${i/%xxx1/}"

                else    until [[ ${var2} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || [[ ${var2} = NULL ]]; do

                                        var2="$(zenity --forms --title="clientid field in table work" --text "Add a clientid"  --separator="," \
                                        --add-entry="WARNING! You either forgot to enter a clientid or didn't enter a number. Please enter a valid clientid: ")"

                                    done

                                    out="$out,${var2}"

                fi  
            
                ;;

        *xxx2) if [[ "${i/%xxx2/}" =~ ^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]]; then

                                out="$out,${i/%xxx2/}"

                                elif [[ "${i/%xxx2/}" = NULL ]]; then

                                        out="$out,${i/%xxx2/}"

                                else    until [[ ${var2} =~ ^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]] || [[ ${var2} = NULL ]]; do

                                        var2="$(zenity --forms --title="number of catchers field in table work" --text "Add number of catchers"  --separator="," \
                                        --add-entry="WARNING! You either forgot to enter number of catchers or didn't enter a number. Please enter a valid number of catchers: ")"

                                        done

                                        out="$out,${var2}"

                                fi

                                ;;

        *xxx3) if [[ "${i/%xxx3/}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then

                                out="$out,${i/%xxx3/}"

                                elif [[ "${i/%xxx3/}" = NULL ]]; then

                                        out="$out,${i/%xxx3/}"

                                else    until [[ ${var2} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || [[ ${var2} = NULL ]]; do

                                        var2="$(zenity --forms --title="front mower wheel hight field in table work" --text "Add front mower wheel hight"  --separator="," \
                                        --add-entry="WARNING! You either forgot to enter a front mower wheel hight or didn't enter a number. Please enter a valid front mower wheel hight: ")"

                                        done

                                        out="$out,${var2}"

                                fi

                                ;;

        *xxx4)  if [[ "${i/%xxx4/}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then

                                out="$out,${i/%xxx4/}"

                                elif [[ "${i/%xxx4/}" = NULL ]]; then

                                        out="$out,${i/%xxx4/}"

                                else    until [[ ${var2} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || [[ ${var2} = NULL ]]; do

                                        var2="$(zenity --forms --title="back mower wheel hight field in table work" --text "Add back mower wheel hight"  --separator="," \
                                        --add-entry="WARNING! You either forgot to enter a back mower wheel hight or didn't enter a number. Please enter a valid back mower wheel hight: ")"

                                        done

                                        out="$out,${var2}"

                                fi

                                ;;

        *xxx5)  if [[ "${i/%xxx5/}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then

                                out="$out,${i/%xxx5/}"

                                elif [[ "${i/%xxx5/}" = NULL ]]; then

                                        out="$out,${i/%xxx5/}"

                                else    until [[ ${var2} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || [[ ${var2} = NULL ]]; do

                                        var2="$(zenity --forms --title="categoryid field in table work" --text "Add a categoryid"  --separator="," \
                                        --add-entry="WARNING! You either forgot to enter a categoryid or didn't enter a number. Please enter a valid categoryid: ")"

                                        done

                                        out="$out,${var2}"

                                fi

                                ;;
            
        *xxx6)  if [[ "${i/%xxx6/}" =~ ^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]]; then

                                out="$out,${i/%xxx6/}"

                                elif [[ "${i/%xxx6/}" = NULL ]]; then

                                        out="$out,${i/%xxx6/}"

                                else    until [[ ${var2} =~ ^[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?$ ]] || [[ ${var2} = NULL ]]; do

                                        var2="$(zenity --forms --title="price field in table work" --text "Add price"  --separator="," \
                                        --add-entry="WARNING! You either forgot to enter price or didn't enter a number. Please enter a valid price: ")"

                                        done

                                        out="$out,${var2}"

                                fi

                                ;;

        *xxx7)  if [[ "${i/%xxx7/}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then

                                out="$out,${i/%xxx7/}"

                                elif [[ "${i/%xxx7/}" = NULL ]]; then

                                        out="$out,${i/%xxx7/}"

                                else    until [[ ${var2} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || [[ ${var2} = NULL ]]; do

                                        var2="$(zenity --forms --title="tip_runid field in table work" --text "Add a tip_runid"  --separator="," \
                                        --add-entry="WARNING! You either forgot to enter a tip_runid or didn't enter a number. Please enter a valid tip_runid: ")"

                                        done

                                        out="$out,${var2}"

                                fi

                                ;;

        *ttt) out="$out,'${i/%ttt/}:00'";;

        *www1)  if [[ "${i/%www1/}" = NULL ]]; then

                out="$out,${i/%www1/}"

                elif [[ -n "${i/%www1/}" ]]; then

                    out="$out,\$\$${i/%www1/}\$\$"

                else    until [[ -n "${var2}" ]]; do

                    var2="$(zenity --forms --title="invoice number field in table work" --text "Add a invoice number"  --separator="," \
                                    --add-entry="WARNING! You either forgot to enter a invoice number. Please enter a invoice number or NULL: ")"

                    if [[ "${var2}" = NULL ]]; then

                        out="$out,${var2}"

                    else

                        out="$out,\$\$${var2}\$\$"

                    fi

                done

                fi
                                ;;

        *www2)  if [[ "${i/%www2/}" = NULL ]]; then

                                out="$out,${i/%www2/}"

                                elif [[ -n "${i/%www2/}" ]]; then

                                        out="$out,\$\$${i/%www2/}\$\$"

                                        else 

                                until [[ -n "${var2}" ]]; do

                                var2="$(zenityi --forms --title="note field in table work" --text "Add a note"  --separator="," \
                                --add-entry="WARNING! You either forgot to enter a note. Please enter a note or NULL: ")"

                                        if [[ "${var2}" = NULL ]]; then

                                                out="$out,${var2}"

                                        else

                                                out="$out,\$\$${var2}\$\$"

                                        fi

                done
                
                fi
                                ;;

        *) out="$out,'${i}:00'";;

esac;
done

echo "${out:1}"

let a++

done
```

Simplified script:

```
#!/bin/bash

work_number="$(zenity --entry --text "ENTER number of work/job entries:" --entry-text "1")"
        a=1

until
        [[ $work_number -lt $a ]]
do

input="$(zenity --forms --title="table work" --text="Add a new job" --separator="," \
       --add-entry="ENTER a: " \
       --add-entry="ENTER invoice reference field: " \
       --add-entry="ENTER b: ")"

input="$( echo "$input" | awk 'BEGIN {  FS="," } { print $1 "," $2"www1" "," $3 ; }' )"

IFS=, read -ra myarray <<<"$input"
out=""

for i in "${myarray[@]}"; do
        case "$i" in
        

        *www1) if [[ "${i/%www1/}" = NULL ]]; then

      out="$out,${i/%www1/}"

elif [[ -n "${i/%www1/}" ]]; then

      out="$out,\$\$${i/%www1/}\$\$"

else    until [[ -n "${var2}" ]]; do

            var2="$(zenity --forms --title="invoice number field in table work" --text "Add a invoice number"  --separator="," \
            --add-entry="WARNING! You either forgot to enter a invoice number. Please enter a invoice number or NULL: ")"

                    if [[ "${var2}" = NULL ]]; then

                         out="${var2}"

                    else

                         out="\$\$${var2}\$\$"

                    fi

        done

 fi
 ;;
 esac
done

out="${out#,}"
printf 'out=%s\n' "$out"
echo "$out"

let a++

done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation

You're reusing the `var2` variable without unsetting it (`unset var2`) or assigning an empty string to it (`var2=''`). Therefore `until [[ -n "${var2}" ]]; do …; done` uses some old *non-empty* value and the  code in place of `…` is never executed.

In the simplified script `var2` is still unset when you first get to `until [[ -n "${var2}" ]]; do`. This is the difference.

Each time you write `until [[ -n "${var2}" ]]; do` ask yourself if the current value of the variable (from the previous loop or so) should matter. If it shouldn't matter then make it not matter: unset the variable just before `until`.

An alternative is to organize your code in functions. In a function in Bash you can define local variables. Local `var2` variable would have nothing to do with `var2` (if any) in the main script or with `var2` in another invocation of this or another function. See `help local` for details. E.g. if you create a function `validate_invoice_number` and define `local var2` in it, then you will be able to use `until [[ -n "${var2}" ]]; do` in the function without any risk that some other (old) `var2` interferes.

---

#### Example

The following piece of code is a flawed attempt to get two random numbers from a range from `0` to `9999`. In Bash `$RANDOM` expands to a random integer from a range from `0` to `32767` We will keep querying Bash for random numbers until (by chance) we get one that meets our expectation. This is similar to your approach where you query the user. It's not the fastest method to get a random integer from the desired range, but in this case it's not fundamentally flawed either. The flaw is in reusing `var2`, like in your code. Diagnostic messages to stderr are here to help you understand what happens.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in 1 2; do
   echo "Loop $i starts. var2 is ${var2:-empty or unset}." >&2
   until [ "$var2" -lt 10000 ] 2>/dev/null; do
      echo "Trying new random number." >&2
      var2="$RANDOM"
   done
   echo "Expectation met. Printing the result." >&2
   echo "$var2"
   echo "Loop $i ends. var2 is ${var2:-empty or unset}." >&2
done
```

Run the code and you will see the second loop does not obtain a new random number at all. Now let's try with `unset`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in 1 2; do
   echo "Loop $i starts. var2 is ${var2:-empty or unset}." >&2
   unset var2
   echo "Loop $i continues. var2 is ${var2:-empty or unset}." >&2
   until [ "$var2" -lt 10000 ] 2>/dev/null; do
      echo "Trying new random number." >&2
      var2="$RANDOM"
   done
   echo "Expectation met. Printing the result." >&2
   echo "$var2"
   echo "Loop $i ends. var2 is ${var2:-empty or unset}." >&2
done
```

Another approach is to use `local var2` in a function:

```
#!/bin/bash

gimme_random () {
   local var2
   echo "Function starts. var2 inside is ${var2:-empty or unset}." >&2
   until [ "$var2" -lt 10000 ] 2>/dev/null; do
      echo "Trying new random number." >&2
      var2="$RANDOM"
   done
   echo "Expectation met. Printing the result." >&2
   echo "$var2"
   echo "Function ends. var2 inside is ${var2:-empty or unset}." >&2
}

for i in 1 2; do
   echo "Loop $i starts. var2 is ${var2:-empty or unset}." >&2
   gimme_random
   echo "Loop $i ends. var2 is ${var2:-empty or unset}." >&2
done
```

This works as expected. The variable inside the function has no connection to the variable outside of the function. When the function is run again, the variable in the new instance is local to the instance.

Try it without `local var2` and it will behave like the first (flawed) snippet. In this case `var2` outside of and inside the function (both instances) is the same `var2`.

Also note if you run the snippets by just pasting them sequentially in a single shell then `var2` (unless local in the function) will remain from one snippet to the other. This will even emphasize the problem.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, but what do you mean by unsetting it and how would you unset var2 so it will work.

Comment: @ChristianHick Try to `unset var2` just before `until`.

Comment: Thanks heaps Kamil that works fine. Will look into using functions.