# Bash function with for loop and nested if statement giving peculiar result

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I have the following bash function that has me boondoggled. If I enter the following in the zenity boxes...

employeeid = 2
categoryid = 3

I get the following: 2 3

if...

employeeid =
categoryid = 3

After a second zenity window opens I enter 2 and I get the following: 2 3

However when I enter

employeeid = 2
categoryid =

No additional Zenity window opens and I get the following: 2

What I really want to end up with is 2,3 after the tests have run.

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

```
#!/bin/bash


num(){
        emp=$(echo "$1" | awk -F, -v  OFS=, '{print $1 "," $2}')

        IFS=, read -ra array1 <<<"$emp"
        
        p=$(for i in "${array1[@]}"
        
        do
                
                if [[ "${i}" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then

                        out="${i}"
                elif
                        [[ "${i}" = NULL ]]; then

                        out="${i}"


                else   local var2

                        until [[ ${var2} =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || [[ ${var2} = NULL ]]; do

                                var2="$(zenity --forms --title="table salaries_wages" --text "Add a number"  --separator="," \
                                --add-entry="WARNING! You either forgot to enter or didn't enter a number. Please enter a valid number: ")"

                         done

                                out="${var2}"

        fi

        echo "$out"
        
done)
      
        echo "$p"
}

input="$(zenity --forms --title="table salaries_wages" --text="Add a new salaries_wages entry" --separator="," \
        --add-entry="ENTER employeeid: " \
        --add-entry="ENTER categoryid: ")"

num "$input"
```

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is wrong here?

Your assumption of how `read` works is different than how `read` actually works. Run this code in Bash:

```
how_many () { IFS=, read -ra array1 <<<"$1"; echo "${#array1[@]}"; }
how_many "2,3"
how_many ",3"
how_many "2,"
```

You will get `2`, `2`, `1`. The last number stands out. It means that trailing separator (`,` in this case) is treated by `read` more like a terminator: the empty field after it is not read into the array and the array ends up being one element too short. If this happens in your code then `for i in "${array1[@]}"` will run the loop for just the first field.

The fix may be to introduce an *extra* `,` as the trailing terminator on purpose. Then `read` will never read the third field, but it will always read two fields (even if the second one is empty). See the difference when I add an extra `,`:

```
how_many () { IFS=, read -ra array1 <<<"$1,"; echo "${#array1[@]}"; }
how_many "2,3"
how_many ",3"
how_many "2,"
how_many ","
```

The output is `2` each time.

To fix your code this way use `<<<"$emp,"` instead of `<<<"$emp"`.

---

If you fix the code then it will misbehave when the `else` block is run more than once (i.e. when both fields are initially invalid); because you're [reusing the `var2` variable](https://superuser.com/a/1568171/432690) again.

I guess you used `local var2` to avoid this, but `local` makes the variable local in a function, not in an `else` block or in a single iteration of a `for` loop. You're reusing `var2` in the same instance of the `num` function.

You're calling the function once. Inside it `var2` is always the same `var2`, `local` only makes it distinct from any `var2` outside this very invocation of the function. If you used `var2` outside of the function, the one in the function would be distinct. If you invoked `num` more than once, each invocation would use its own distinct `var2`. Neither of these happens. You're calling the function once and reusing the variable *there*. When two fields are invalid the variable is used for the first field and then *reused* for the second field.

But if you rebuild your code so some function (e.g. `validate`) is called from within the loop:

```
for i in "${array1[@]}"; do validate "$i"; …
```

and use `local var2` in the `validate` function, then `var2` in each invocation of the function will be distinct. This is how `local` can help. In each loop `validate` will be called anew, its local variable(s) will be initialized fresh without any connection to other variable(s) with the same name(s). However you will still be able to reuse a local variable *inside* the function in a way that breaks something (similarly to how you're currently reusing `var2` in the `num` function).

After I wrote the above, a added an example to the [already linked answer](https://superuser.com/a/1568171/432690).

---

Note `p=$(stuff); echo "$p"` is almost equivalent to `echo "$(stuff)"`, which almost always should be just `stuff`. Please read [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1352851/432690) where it elaborates on `var=$(stuff); echo "$var"`.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, so I tried the following. I changed to `<<<"$emp,"` and rebuilt the code to `for i in "${array1[@]}"; do validate "$i"; …`. Then I wrote a function `validate(){ local "$1" }` and placed it at the top of the script. (I tried this with and without quotation. This however only works if I provide two fields.There is still a problem with this. The output is also on two separate lines and not the same line. What I really want is 2,3 on the same line.

Comment: @ChristianHick Of course there's still a problem. A function that only calls `local` and exits is a no-op. (Besides `validate(){ local "$1" }` is syntactically invalid; and `local "$1"` is not `local var2` you need.) The problem is some piece of code reuses `var2`. If we think `local` can help then we need to *move this piece of code to a function* and use `local` *there*. I named the function `validate` because it should contain your code that *validates*. Maybe I will provide an example in few hours; no time now.

Comment: @ChristianHick I added an example to the linked answer. My intention is to let it deal with the issue of a variable being reused. Then let the above answer deal mainly with the issue of `read` reading fewer fields than expected. If you can't get the output to be in the same line, then it's *yet another* issue. This site works best in "one issue – one question" regime. If I were you I would ask another question. I would make it as MCVE as I can: hopefully without `zenity`, `awk`, `read`. What have you tried? Here you `echo "$out"` without even trying to put `,` after it and to suppress newline.

Comment: Thanks Kamil for taking the time to elaborate in the linked answer. I really much appreciate your patience. The solution that I will be going with from your recommendation is to change to ```<<<"$emp,"``` remove ```validate(){ local "$1" }``` and replace ```local var2``` with ```unset var2``` after ```else```. This gives the desired result in all scenarios. I will post an additional question on how to get 2,3 in one line rather than 2 3 in two lines.